# Save while loop results as numpy array in python?

Tags: python

Fairly new at coding, Im using python to do a monte carlo simulation. Not really sure how I would go about this, the end result would be to graph out the results from the steadystate function.

```
import random
import numpy as np

def steadystate():
    p=0.88
    Cout=4700000000
    LambdaAER=0.72
    Vol=44.5
    Depo=0.42
    Uptime=0.1
    Effic=0.38
    Recirc=4.3
    x = random.randint(86900000,2230000000000)
    conc = ((p*Cout*LambdaAER)+(x/Vol))/(LambdaAER+Depo+(Uptime*Effic*Recirc))
    return conc

x = 0
while x < 10000:
    result = steadystate()
    print(result)
    x+=1
```

Right now I just want to save the results from the while loop as an array so I can graph it. Ive tried appending it but it wouldnt print anything.

Comment: `results = np.array([steadystate() for _ in range(1000)])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve what you need would be to generate your random integers as an array to start with, e.g.:

```py
size = 10000

# generate 10000 (size) random integers as a numpy array
x = np.random.randint(86900000, 2230000000000, size=size)

p = 0.88
Cout = 4700000000
LambdaAER = 0.72
Vol = 44.5
Depo = 0.42
Uptime = 0.1
Effic = 0.38
Recirc = 4.3

result = ((p*Cout*LambdaAER)+(x/Vol))/(LambdaAER+Depo+(Uptime*Effic*Recirc))
```

The `result` object will also be a numpy array of the same size as `x`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Both @paime and your solutions work very well.